# Crystal Reports XI - IF Date1 NOT LIKE Date2

Tags: sql, date, filter

I'm relatively new working with Crystal Reports and have came across an issue I can't locate the answer for.

I have two tables, both have the field Date within them but are not related. I want to pull through data on Crystal where the Date in Customer does not equal the Date in Staff. In addition I am also trying to pull through data where the date in Staff is null. Currently my query currently looks like this:

isnull ({Staff.Date})
OR 
NOT ({Staff.Date} LIKE '{Customer.Date}')

This query does not work and returns 'A String is Required' and highlights the second ({Staff.Date}.

I hope the above makes sense.

Many thanks in advance,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE is a string function. The error is basically telling you that the Staff.Date field isn't a string. As it's a date then the behaviour should be expected.

To do the comparison with a LIKE you need to convert the DateTime type to a String.

However you should just be able to compare the dates directly if they are both DateTime types.

I've not used Crystal in a while but have you tried something as simple as:

```
isnull ({Staff.Date}) OR NOT ({Staff.Date} = {Customer.Date})
```

There are also a number of Date functions that you could use (e.g. DateDiff) if you need to fine tune the results.